# Prevent text inside group from getting stretched on group resizing in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

So I wrote this code:

```
/* Create a rectangle object */
            let rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
                left: this.convertCoordinates(objectOnOffset.x, this.canvas.getWidth()),
                top: this.convertCoordinates(objectOnOffset.y, this.canvas.getHeight()),
                width: this.convertCoordinates(objectOnOffset.width, this.canvas.getWidth()),
                height: this.convertCoordinates(objectOnOffset.height, this.canvas.getHeight()),
                stroke: 'orange',
                noScaleCache: false,
                strokeWidth: 4,
                strokeUniform: true,
                fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'
            });

            /* Create a Text object */
            let text = new fabric.Text("Person 456", {
                top: rectangle.top + 5,
                left: rectangle.left + 5,
                fill: "white",
                fontSize: 25,
                fontFamily: "arial",
                lockScalingX: true,
                lockScalingY: true,
                width: 10,
                height:10
            });

            /* Add Object into a single group */
            let objectGroup = new fabric.Group([rectangle, text],
                {
                    noScaleCache: false,
                    selectable: true,
                    cornerSize: 8,
                    cornerColor: 'rgb(0,255,255)',
                    transparentCorners: false,
                    borderColor: 'rgb(0,255,255)',
                    lockRotation: true,
                    lockUniScaling: true,
                    width: rectangle.width,
                    lockScalingFlip: true
                }
            );
```

As it can be seen in the result that the text gets stretched when I resize the group, how can I fix the size of this text, is there any property for this ?

[image]

Comment: Hi  Did yoy find any solution

Comment: @DineshRawat I was able to find a workaround for this problem by rendering text on canvas directly inside the Rect object instead of grouping elements together resulting in a custom labeled rectangle object, turns out, fabric.js has a built-in utility for creating custom classes, so upon resizing the rectangle, I just re-rendered the text which prevented it from stretching.